# Galaxy Note Not Working with Apple Router

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

I have a new Galaxy Note 10.1 (2014) tablet that I absolutely love. I've been using it to take lecture notes and the thing is great.

The tablet's wifi works fine with every network...except the one I have at home. I have an Apple Airport Express that I use as a hub for my university's 100mbps Ethernet line; I've contacted Samsung support only to get the standard "talk to your ISP about DNS settings" canned response.

The weird thing is, the tablet says it's connected to my network, and my computer says that the tablet is connected as well...but no application that involves internet works...only on my home network.
[image]

I've run across a number of forum posts addressing this issue, but few dealing specifically with the Apple hardware and DNS settings. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Apple almost always has compatibility issues...

Comment: going to best buy to grab a non-apple router later. serious issues with my Dell inspiron laptop too. competition is good for business, but these hardware firms make it a nightmare owning from more than one manufacturer..